# trouble using mediaplug-ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an urgent issue.

I'm using mediaplug-ruby to get the images cropped on the fly.

I went through mediaplug-ruby doc(the http://github.com/intridea/mediaplug-ruby/blob/master/README.rdoc) and it says, i have to supply my site url, which id id.

The image-url i supplied is:http://s3.amazonaws.com/lifetuner-production/photos/41/JPond_user_photo_medium.jpg
The actions on it being: resize (width=100 and format= png), crop (location=center, width=100,height=100, format=png)

And, my site = lifetuner.org (yet under development)

So, the final url = http://mp.lifetuner.org/mp/get?mpsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Flifetuner-production%2Fphotos%2F41%2FJPond_user_photo_medium.jpg&mpaction=resize%20width%3D100%20format%3Dpng%3Bcrop%20location%3Dcenter%20width%3D100%20height%3D100%20format%3Dpng

This url ain't working.

Am i missing something, should i have some background-config or should i add something at the server-side.

Plz, urgent-help needed !

Comment: You should refrase your question. I can't make head or tail of it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your trouble may be in the URL.

The one you supplied decodes to

```
http://mp.lifetuner.org/mp/get?mpsrc=http://s3.amazonaws.com/lifetuner-production/photos/41/JPond_user_photo_medium.jpg&mpaction=resize width=100 format=png;crop location=center width=100 height=100 format=png
```

In the doc example, their url decodes to

```
http://mp.yourserver.com/mp/get?mpsrc=http://some.url&mpaction=resize width=>100 height=>100 format=jpg;crop location=center width=100 height=100 format=jpg
```

You're missing the > after the equals sign in some directives... Hope that helps a bit, though of course I have no idea if that's all the problem since I've not used this service personally.

Actually it looks like the angle bracket comes from how the size is specified

```
.resize('>100x>100')
```

which indicates if you're increasing or decreasing the size according to http://wiki.gomediaplug.com/mediaplug/published/Image+API

But ultimately, since your site returns a 404 type page - I'd make sure the service is configured correctly on your server.